# Non-recursive way of getting the depth of a binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, data-structures, binary-tree

I am trying to use a non-recursive way of getting the depth of a binary tree, but the codes below didn't see to work well, tried to debug a lot, haven't got any clue. Please help. Thanks.

```
public int treeDepthNonRecursion(TreeNode root) {
    int max = 0;
    int curSum = 0;
    if(root==null) {
        return 0;
    }

    TreeNode temp = root;
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    Stack<Integer> stack2 = new Stack<Integer>();
    stack.push(temp);
    stack2.push(curSum);

    while(!stack.isEmpty()) {
        if(temp!=null)  {
            stack.push(temp);
            stack2.push(curSum++);
            System.out.println("here curSum="+curSum);
            temp = temp.getLeftChild();
        } else {
            temp = stack.pop();
            curSum = stack2.pop();
            if(curSum>max) {
                max = curSum;
            }
            temp = temp.getRightChild();
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```

Comment: What happened when you ran that code? What were you trying to do in more detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an error (probably the one you're looking for) there:

```
temp = temp.getRightChild();
```

Before this line, you have a node `temp` and its associated depth, (for example curSum=2). After this line, and in the next loop, temp will be the right child, but the associated depth will still be the one of the parent (to follow the example, still curSum=2).

You can fix your code by increasing curSum after getting the right child:

```
temp = temp.getRightChild();
curSum += 1;
```

---

Your code is hard to understand, it seems like you're traversing the tree in a leftChild->node->rightChild order.

I suggest you to have a simpler algorithm, with the exact same computation for each node popped out of the stack. For example:

```
public static int treeDepthNonRecursion(TreeNode root) {
    int maxDepth = 0;
    int depth = 0;
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    TreeNode node = root;
    Stack<TreeNode> nodesStack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    Stack<Integer> depthStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    nodesStack.push(node);
    depthStack.push(depth);

    while (!nodesStack.isEmpty()) {
        node = nodesStack.pop();
        depth = depthStack.pop();
        maxDepth = Math.max(maxDepth, depth);
        if (node.getLeftChild() != null) {
            nodesStack.push(node.getLeftChild());
            depthStack.push(depth + 1);
        }
        if (node.getRightChild() != null) {
            nodesStack.push(node.getRightChild());
            depthStack.push(depth + 1);
        }
    }

    return maxDepth;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Yeah, It worked after I add this line,
"curSum += 1;", and also checked ur codes, it's easier! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

A non recursive, non stack based traverse of a tree can be performed if you maintain parent references in each node. This can be performed as shown below.

```
public class Tree< E > {

    private class Node {

        public E val = null;

        public Node parent = null;

        public Node right = null;
        public Node left = null;

    }

    private Node root = null;

    public int getDepth() {
        int maxDepth = -1;
        int curDepth = 0;

        Node prev = null;
        Node cur = root;
        while( cur != null ) {
            if( prev == cur.parent ) {
                if( cur.left != null ) {
                    curDepth++;
                    prev = cur;
                    cur = cur.left;

                    continue;
                }

                prev = null;
            }

            if( prev == cur.left ) {
                if( cur.right != null ) {
                    curDepth++;
                    prev = cur;
                    cur = cur.right;

                    continue;
                }

                prev = null;
            }

            if( prev == cur.right ) {
                if( curDepth > maxDepth ) {
                    maxDepth = curDepth;
                }
                curDepth--;

                prev = cur;
                cur = cur.parent;
            }
        }

        return maxDepth;
    }
```

You can edit the above solution to perform pre, in, and post order traversals of a tree. This does come with the overhead of another reference in each node. I originally wrote this for a homework assignment and rewrote it here from memory. I am not entirely sure if it is 100% correct, but works from my limited testing.

Comment: Thanks very much, it did help. StackOverflow only let me accept one answer. Thanks.